# how to write xpath expression

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

i have two xml documents resembling the following:

first:

```
<root>
<recordType>ABCD</recordType>
<field>
  <value>red</field>
  <id>1234</field>
</field>
</root>
```

second:

```
<root>
<recordType>EFGH</recordType>
<field>
  <value>red</field>
  <id>1234</field>
</field>
</root>
```

for the above xml i have xpath expression for allowedValues as XPATH:recordType:ABCD;EFGH
    This expression is working fine, but for the below xml

```
<root>
<record isRecord="true">
<field id="220" isRecord="false" value="Red" />
<field id="221" isRecord="true" value="Small" />
<field id="222" isRecord="true" value="25" />
</record>
<record isRecord="true">
<field id="220" value="Red" />
<field id="221" value="Large" />
<field id="222" value="50" />
</record>
</root>
```

i want XPATH for if field id=220 and isRecord="false" and value="Red".

Answer (score 0):

Will the following xpath expression fulfill your expectations:

`/root/record/field[@id='220' and @isRecord='false' and @value='Red']`

*Matching result:*

`<field id="220" isRecord="false" value="Red" />`

Comment: This is not working for me....
But when i tried /root/record/field/@id:220

it is working fine..

but when i check for /root/record/field/@id:221 .... this is not working for the above xml.. it is not considering second tag..

Comment: "/root/record/field/@id:220" is not a valid xpath.